# HTTP status 500: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, jdbc

I'm getting the following error:

«HTTP Status 500 -The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request» as it is shown as following. I really don't know why this class cannot be resolve. Anyone could help me to fix the error please? Thanks.:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /supprimer.jsp
List cannot be resolved to a type
38:                 </TR>
39:                 <%
40:                     
41:                     List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>(com.prog.GestionLivres.LivresDisponibles());
42:             
43:                     int id = 0;
44:                     String box = null;


An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /supprimer.jsp
ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
38:                 </TR>
39:                 <%
40:                     
41:                     List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>(com.prog.GestionLivres.LivresDisponibles());
42:             
43:                     int id = 0;
44:                     String box = null;


An error occurred at line: 45 in the jsp file: /supprimer.jsp
Iterator cannot be resolved to a type
42:             
43:                     int id = 0;
44:                     String box = null;
45:                     Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
46:                     
47:                     while (it.hasNext())
48:                     {


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.21 logs.


<%@page import="com.prog.GestionLivres"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%-- <%@ page errorPage="erreur.jsp" %> --%>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration" %>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Supprimer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <%
            Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
            while (names.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String name = (String) names.nextElement();
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(name);
                sb.deleteCharAt(0);
                com.prog.GestionLivres.Supprimer(sb.toString());
            }           
        %>
        <BR>
        <DIV class="navigator">
        <A href="ajouter.jsp">Ajouter</a>
        <A id="currenttab" href="supprimer.jsp">Supprimer</A>
        </DIV>
        <BR> <BR> <BR>
        <FORM action="supprimer.jsp" method="post">
            <TABLE>
                <TR>
                    <TH>Auteur</TH>
                    <TH>Titre</TH>
                    <TH>Année</TH>
                    <TH>Remarques</TH>
                </TR>
                <%

                    List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>(com.prog.GestionLivres.LivresDisponibles());

                    int id = 0;
                    String box = null;
                    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

                    while (it.hasNext())
                    {
                        id = Integer.parseInt(it.next());
                        out.print("<TR>");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            out.print("<TD>");
                            out.print(it.next());
                            out.print("</TD>");
                        }
                        out.print("<TD>");
                        box = "<INPUT name=r" + id + " type=’checkbox’>";
                        out.print(box);
                        out.print("</TD>");
                        out.print("</TR>");
                    }
                %>
            </TABLE>
            <BR>
            <INPUT type="submit" value="Supprimer">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>


package com.prog;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GestionLivres
{
    static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bibliotheques";

    public static void Insert(String auteur, String titre, int annee, String remarques)
    {
        try
        {
            String insert = "INSERT INTO livres(auteur, titre, annee, remarques)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            ps.setString(1, auteur);
            ps.setString(2, titre);
            ps.setInt(3, annee);
            ps.setString(4, remarques);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionLivres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> LivresDisponibles()
    {
        List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM livres");
                    while(result.next())
                    {
                        list.add(result.getString("id"));
                        list.add(result.getString("auteur"));
                        list.add(result.getString("titre"));
                        //list.add(result.getInt("annee"));
                        list.add(result.getString("remarques"));
                    }
                conn.close();
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionLivres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void Supprimer(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            String supprimerEnregistrement = "DELETE from livres WHERE id = ?";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(supprimerEnregistrement);
            ps.setString(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionLivres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `java.util.List` and other classes its complaining about in your JSP, as in:

`<%@ page import="java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.Iterator"%>`

Thats just to get it to compile. IMO this design is not recommended, all of the logic should be in the controller and you should only send simple beans (POJOs) to the view layer for rendering.